# gDBView is not defined and xul

Tags: javascript, xul, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'm trying to write a Thunderbird extension using XUL, a custom button that accesses the currently shown email message body and does something with it.

Apparently this would be possible using the global variable `gDBView`, as in the [Display Mail User Agent extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/display-mail-user-agent/):

```
var msgURI = null ;

if ( gDBView )
{
  msgURI = gDBView.URIForFirstSelectedMessage ;
}

if ( msgURI == null )
{
  return ;
}

var messenger = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/messenger;1"].createInstance (Components.interfaces.nsIMessenger ) ;
var msgService = messenger.messageServiceFromURI ( msgURI ) ;
```

Unfortunately if in my extension I replicate the row:

```
msgURI = gDBView.URIForFirstSelectedMessage ;
```

I get the following error from the Thunderbird console:

> gDBView is not defined

Is there a reason why this happens? And is this the best (and correct) way to access a mail body?

Comment: I guess that you put that line into a script loaded by a mail window overlay? When do you run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running your script in the wrong context, as Wladimir correctly guessed. An easy way to check that `gDBView` exists is, in the menus, to hit `Tools > Error Console`, then paste `top.opener.gDBView`, then hit `Enter`. This returns (for me) `[xpconnect wrapped (nsISupports, nsIMsgDBView, nsITreeView)]` which means the object indeed does exist.